# jQuery trigger click on radio not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger a click on radio buttons. I have done this successfully on another project so I cannot see why it is not working in this case.

Here is my HTML (taken from `Contact form 7`):

```
<span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
  <label>
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Yes</span>
    <input type="radio" name="example-name" value="Yes" checked="checked">
  </label>
</span>

<span class="wpcf7-list-item last">
  <label>
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">No</span>
    <input type="radio" name="example-name" value="No">
  </label>
</span>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery("#yes-btn").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass('checked');
        jQuery("input[value='Yes']").trigger('click').addClass("working");
    });

    jQuery("#no-btn").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass('checked');
        jQuery("input[value='No']").trigger('click').addClass("working");
    });

});
```

I know the selector is working correctly because the `.addClass()` works just fine.

I have also tried `.prop("checked", true)` instead of `trigger("click")` without success.

I am using jQuery 3.3.1.

How to fix this?

Comment: Where is element with `id="yes-btn"`?

Comment: there's no problems in the code, it should work just fine.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev It's write above wpcf7-list-item first in the DOM

Comment: @Aboalnaga I wish that were the case.

Comment: this line works `jQuery("input[value='No']").trigger('click').addClass("working");` and you say the class `checked` was added successfully

Comment: @Aboalnaga
The addClass("working") works just fine on the same element.

The addClass("checked") is for something different.

Comment: I just realized, it is working. I thought it wasn't working because nothing was updating in Chrome's DOM inspector except the class. Is that possibly a bug in chrome's inspector?

Answer (score 0):

It works when you change the 'single quotes' from around yes and no to "double quotes". Also works with no quotes around the Yes and No, must not like single quotes in the selector.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#yes-btn").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('checked');
        jQuery('input[value="Yes"]').trigger('click').addClass("working");
    });

    jQuery("#no-btn").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('checked');
        jQuery('input[value="No"]').trigger('click').addClass("working");
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
<label>
<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Yes</span>
<input type="radio" name="example-name" value="Yes" checked="checked">
</label>
</span>

<span class="wpcf7-list-item last">
<label>
<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">No</span>
<input type="radio" name="example-name" value="No">
</label>
</span>

<button id="yes-btn">Yes</button>

<button id="no-btn">No</button>
```

Comment: the ids belongs to other elements as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349760/jquery-trigger-click-on-radio-not-working?noredirect=1#comment91644880_52349760)